# Working on an approximation of $\pi$. How do I demonstrate an inequality on the taylor expansion of arctan?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm struggling  with the following inequality.  In particular, I don't understand how to demonstrate that this term is larger than the left hand side for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  It seems to be another term for the sequence but I don't have the intuition for its growth.

**Main Question:**
Show that $$\left| \tan^{-1}(x) -\left(x  -  \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \dots + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{t^{2n-1}}{2n-1 } \right)  \right| \leq \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

> **For context,**  I am trying to show an approximation of $\pi$. The steps for the proof are as follows:
>
> Show that $$\frac{1}{1+t^2} = 1 - t^2 + t^4 - \dots +(-1)^{n-1}t^{2n-2} + (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n}}{1+t^2}$$
>
> Integrate both sides to show that  $$\tan^{-1} (x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5} - \dots +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1} + \int_0^{x} \frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{1+t^2}dt$$
>
> Show that $$\left| \tan^{-1}(x) -\left(x  -  \frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{x^5}{5} - \dots + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{t^{2n-1}}{2n-1 } \right)  \right| \leq \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
>
> Show that  $$\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}  \frac{\pi}{4}$$
>
> Finally show that  $$\left|\frac{\pi}{4} - \left(\left(\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}\right) - \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2}\right) + \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2^5} +
> \frac{1}{3^5}\right) - \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} + \frac{1}{3^{2n-1}}\right)\right) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n\cdot2^{2n-1}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

I assume you have already shown that
$$\frac{1}{1+t^2} = 1 - t^2 + t^4 - \dots +(-1)^{n-1}t^{2n-2} + (-1)^n \frac{t^{2n}}{1+t^2}.$$

This implies that 
$$\left|\frac{1}{1+t^2} -\left( 1 - t^2 + t^4 - \dots +(-1)^{n-1}t^{2n-2} \right)\right| = \frac{t^{2n}}{1+t^2} \le t^{2n}.$$

That is,
$$-t^{2n}\le \frac{1}{1+t^2} -\left( 1 - t^2 + t^4 - \dots +(-1)^{n-1}t^{2n-2} \right)\le t^{2n}.$$

Now try integrating this inequality.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something "obvious"

Comment: Welcome! I realised the question also got you to the step $$\tan^{-1} (x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5} - \dots +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1} + \int_0^{x} \frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{1+t^2}dt.$$ So you can also use this: this equation tells us that $$\tan^{-1} (x) -\left( x - \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5} - \dots +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1} \right) = \int_0^{x} \frac{(-1)^nt^{2n}}{1+t^2}dt.$$ You can now take absolute values and use the triangle inequality for integrals (noting that $\left|\frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{1+t^2}\right| \le t^{2n}$).

Comment: Yes, however I am unfamiliar with integrating the right hand side (rusty with calculus), and figured there was an elementary way to handle it.

Comment: Oh I see, with the note that you wrote, it simplifies the inequality, and makes applying the triangle inequality much simpler

Comment: Correct, we don't need to integrate the original right-hand side, we can use the triangle inequality and that note to simplify it and achieve the desired bounds as follows: $$\begin{align*}\left| \int_0^x \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{1+t^2}\, dt \right|&\le \int_0^x \left|\frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{1+t^2} \right| \, dt \quad (\text{assuming }x \ge 0) \\ &\le \int_0^x t^{2n}\, dt \quad \Bigg{(}\text{since }\left|\frac{(-1)^n t^{2n}}{1+t^2} \right| \le t^{2n} \Bigg{)}\\ &= \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}. \end{align*}$$